# Qt: the most efficient way of displaying real time plain text?

Tags: c++, qt

What is the most efficient way of displaying real time plain text?

If I need to display large amount of changing text with high frequency.
What is the best solution?
I have tried QLabel, QPlaintextEdit and I also tried to rewrite a widget's paintEvent and do painting there. But they all do not work very well.
Due to the platform limitation, I cannot use QGLwidget or openGL support.

And the texts need to be grouped in related widgets where the user can perform some basic interaction(like selecting) with those widgets. The expected thing is something like this:[image]

EDIT: 
The data comes from many different vehicles' sensors, you could consider that I store the incoming data simply in several arrays. The method I have tried all resulted in a slow responding GUI thread.

Comment: How is the text to be displayed originating? Does it come from some network connection, or some device? What does "not working very well" means? Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: what is actually going wrong , with your efforts ? how often is the data received and what is the source of data generation ( e.g. socket ? )

Comment: The data is received about 2Hz for each vehicle. But there could be hundreds of them.

Comment: Displaying is never good at real time. Working on data should be no problem, but i would queue (signal/slot with queued connection) data to be displayed since you will always have an output lag introduced as soon as you want to display data. Fastest would probably be to have a lightweight widget the display will be drawn on.

Comment: You don't explain how is the data coming. If it is on some remote vehicule, you probably are using some network socket and protocol, and you should explain with more details how (and what protocol). If possible show some of your code.

Comment: The data is coming through several serial port, each of them have a unique listener, once the data is received it will be sent to a central data storage in the GUI thread.

Comment: I wonder if the lagginess is not to do with the display, but some interaction with the serial comms and/or updating the data storage.  Can you write a debug version that uses random data and does not use comm ports?  How fast can you get the display to run?

Comment: I would store the input in some type of container which is easily read, and later messages overwrite earlier ones.  Every X milliseconds (probably 250) I'd read this container (using QTimer) and display the text.  As per before, real time is total overkill.